# Making toolbar hidden

Tags: iphone, toolbar

I have class A which has a toolbar (created programatically) with property(nonatomic,retain). In another class B I want to make the toolbar of class A hidden. How can I do that? I am using

```
ClassA *aobj=[[classA alloc] init];
[aobj.toolbar sethidden:yes];
```

but it isn't working.

Answer (score 3):

If this is from a view controller then you should probably do something like this:

```
[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden: YES animated: YES];
```

Comment: I guess most people are coding to the 3.x SDK by now, but it's worth noting that this wouldn't work with older versions of iPhone OS.

Comment: no..... the toolbar in question is in class A while coding is in class B. This is nt what i was looking for.